# How do I use an existing folder hierarchy structure as template to create new folder with the same hierarchy structure?

Tags: right-click, windows-explorer, directory-structure, create-directory

I have created a working script that I've added to the windows registry. When a person right clicks in windows explorer, they can click on "Create New Job Folder" that creates a new folder with a specified hierarchy but it asks the user for the name of the folder.

I'm trying to figure out how to edit my current script to create the hierarchy based on a certain folder. This folder will basically be a template so as I update the folder structure to better suit my needs, each subsequent folder I create using the script will reflect those changes. Thanks in advance for any help!

Here is what I have in my current working script:

```
    set verbose=NO
    @echo off

    set mydir = %cd%
    cd %mydir%
    cls

    call:main
    goto:eof

    :main
    set /p job=Enter Job Name:

    call:check

    if %choice%==2 (echo Creating folder. Please Wait... & timeout 1 > nul & 

    call:createDirectory)
    goto main

    :check
    echo[
    if exist "%job%" (echo ERROR: Folder already exists. Please choose a different name. 
    & set choice=1) else (set choice=2)
    echo[
    exit /b

    :createDirectory
    md "%job%"

    md "%job%"\1.Development
    md "%job%"\1.Development\1.Budgets
    md "%job%"\1.Development\2.Manufacturers

    md "%job%"\"2.Plans and Specs"
    md "%job%"\"2.Plans and Specs"\1.Plans
    md "%job%"\"2.Plans and Specs"\2.Specs

    md "%job%"\3.Pricing
    md "%job%"\3.Pricing\1.Quotes
    md "%job%"\3.Pricing\2.Worksheets

    md "%job%"\4.Sumbittals
    md "%job%"\4.Sumbittals\"1.Submittal Reviews"

    md "%job%"\5.Orders
    md "%job%"\5.Orders\"1.Order Summaries"
    md "%job%"\5.Orders\"2.Confirmation Pages"

    md "%job%"\6.Closeout
    md "%job%"\6.Closeout\"1.O&M Manuals"
    md "%job%"\6.Closeout\2.Warranty

    exit
```

Comment: `xcopy /t` will copy a directory structure without copying files.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`FOR /D`](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/cmd.mspx?mfr=true) to list the subfolders of the current directory or `FOR /D /R` ([undocumented? /r flag](https://ss64.com/nt/for_d.html)) to list all subfolders in the current directory recursively.

```
@echo off
setlocal
set base=c:\mytemplatedir
set mydir=%cd%
goto main

:enumdir
pushd "%base%\%~1\%~2"
for /D %%a in (*) do (
    md "%mydir%\%~1\%~2\%%~a"
    call :enumdir "%~1\%~2" "%%~a"
)
popd
@goto :EOF

:main
call :enumdir . .
```

or you can use `FOR /R` to walk a folder tree for files `(*)` or folders `(.)`.

If you know your template folders might contain &, ! or % in their names you might want to consider using a .vbs file instead so you don't have to deal with special batch characters.